# Add eight characters after a certain character from CharArray to a String

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, char

I have this string:

```
}1311202013112020607169018}1611202016112020}1411202014112020626948615}1511202015112020}1811202018112020
```

To help you understand I will split it like this:

```
}13112020 13112020607169018 }16112020 16112020 }14112020 14112020626948615 }15112020 15112020 
}18112020 181120207834
```

What I am trying to do is to take first eight characters (numbers) after the '}' character, which represent dates. The other numbers I do not need at all.

I have tried many different ways to do it using a for loop and this is the last bit of code I ended up on.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Char.length; i++) {

     if(Char[i] == '}') {

          newString = newString + Char[i + 6];

     } 
}
```

So I am trying to end up with a string looking like this

```
}13112020}16112020}14112020}15112020}18112020
```

Also if someone could give me a tip on how I would be able to create (if it's even possible) x amount of new strings each one being a different name containing just one of these dates.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage regex to find all substrings that match your pattern. The regex in this case would be `"\}[0-9]{8}"` (you say 6 chars after the close brace but your example shows 8).

In Java, you can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to compile this regex and find all matching substrings:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

String str = "}1311202013112020607169018}1611202016112020}1411202014112020626948615}1511202015112020}1811202018112020";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\}[0-9]{8}");  // have to double-escape brace
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

// we use StringBuilder to concatenate the results
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while(matcher.find()) {
  result.append(matcher.group());
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't know where I saw six characters, I edited that now thanks. Also thank you for all the answers but this works pretty well without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a regex string split here:

```java
String input = "}1311202013112020607169018}1611202016112020}1411202014112020626948615}1511202015112020}1811202018112020";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\}\\d{8})|(?=\\})");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[}13112020, 13112020607169018, }16112020, 16112020, }14112020, 14112020626948615,
 }15112020, 15112020, }18112020, 18112020]
```

The regex used says to split at any point in the string where:

```
(?<=\\}\\d{8})   what precedes is } followed by 8 digits
|                OR
(?=\\})          what follows is }
```

**Edit:**

Given the answer you accepted, it seems you actually want this output:

```
}13112020}16112020}14112020}15112020}18112020
```

For this, I would suggest a simple regex replacement:

```
String input = "}1311202013112020607169018}1611202016112020}1411202014112020626948615}1511202015112020}1811202018112020";
String output = input.replaceAll("(\\}\\d{8})\\d*", "$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
}13112020}16112020}14112020}15112020}18112020
```

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand ,  you need some thing like this

```
static List<String> getDates(String str){
      String[] arr = str.split("}");
      ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i].trim(); //remove any spaces
            if (arr[i].length() == 0) continue;
            out.add(arr[i].subString(0 , Math.min(arr[i].length() , 6)); //to prevent any OutOfBounds Errors
            
      }
      return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way:

```
String text = new String(Char);
List<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] split = text.split("}");

for(String first: split) {
    lists.add(first.substring(0,5));
}
```